# Get the ID of a child entity just after a parent has been saved

Tags: nhibernate, identity

There is a parent entity that has a collection of child entities (cascale=all) and each child entity has a collection of grand-child entities (cascale=all).

Given a session, I create a grand-child and add it to the children of a child in the parent and since I also modified some other objects inside the hierarchy, I call Session.SaveOrUpdate on the root (parent).

After this I need the id of the grand-child entity but it is 0.

Now if I additionally call Session.SaveOrUpdate on the grand-child too, then I can get its new id. Is it normal behavior? With the cascades set to all, I would have thought that I could get the id when saving the parent.

Any enlightments?

Comment: generated by identity? and is the FlushMode set to Commit?

Comment: @dotjoe: yes, by identity. I didn't change FlushMode so I guess it is Auto by default?

Comment: Is the new entity saved to the DB when the ID is still 0?

Comment: @Florian: Yes it is. As soon as SaveOrUpdate returns, I can see the record in the DB with a new ID. But in the code, the id is still 0.

Answer (score 1):

SaveOrUpdate, when called on an already-persistent interface does nothing.

You can either call `session.Persist(parent)`, which will cascade, or call `session.Save(grandChild)` as you're already doing (there's nothing wrong with this, although I wonder what you need that Id for)

Comment: you say "does nothing" but just after the call to SaveOrUpdate I can see the new grand-child in the DB. I need the Id because this happens in a remote service and the caller of the service needs this id (this is returned by json).